# Plotting wind speed and wind direction over time

Tags: matlab, plot

I'm trying to make a plot that can display both wind speed and wind direction over time. A colleague suggested adding a line pointing in the wind direction to each point on a time-series plot of wind speed.

I thought it would be fairly simple to calculate the line. I used trig formulas from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/656511). However the plot is not displaying as I'd expect. All of the lines look as if they have zero slope rather than vary from -1 to 1.

Here is my code:

```
wdates = [   7.357325746759259E5;   7.357325747916667E5;   7.357325749074074E5;    7.357325750231481E5;   7.357325751388889E5;   7.357325752546296E5;   7.357325753703704E5;   7.357325754861111E5;   7.357325756018518E5;   7.357325757175926E5;   7.357325758333333E5;   7.357325759490741E5;   7.357325760648148E5];
topspeed = rand(size(wdates)) * 2;

toprdir = [0 pi/6 pi/4 pi/3 pi/2 2*pi/3 3*pi/4 pi 5*pi/4 4*pi/3 3*pi/2 5*pi/3 7*pi/4];
toprdir = toprdir';

h = figure(1);
plot(wdates,topspeed,'s');
datetick('x')
hold all;

%find slope
topslopes = tan(toprdir);

for i=1:length(wdates)
    %find start point.
    clear x;
    clear y;
    x(1) = wdates(i);
    y(1) = topspeed(i);
    d = .0001;

    %x(2) = d * cos(atan(topslopes(i))) + x(1); %did not work?
    %y(2) = d * sin(atan(topslopes(i))) + y(1); %did not work?
    x(2) = d * cos(toprdir(i)) + x(1);
    y(2) = d * sin(toprdir(i)) + y(1);
    plot(x,y);
end
```

[And here is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwhGu.png).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeing that all the lines look like they have a slope of zero because your axes have very different ranges.

Instead, create a scaling factor based on your axes ranges. Note that, I just approximated values for dy, dx, but you should calculate what they should be based on your data and physical dimensions of each of your axis (e.g. make sure a 45 deg line looks like 45 degrees). You can use "axis square" to make dimensions the same.

```
dy = 1;
dx = 0.001;

x(2) = dx * cos(toprdir(i)) + x(1);
y(2) = dy * sin(toprdir(i)) + y(1);
```

With these lines modified, the resulting graph looks as follows:
[image]

Comment: Thanks! I'm pretty close but that angles aren't quite right. For example, I checked the 45 degree angle in ImageJ and it was only 38 degrees. [result](http://i.imgur.com/JGrtCYT.png) --> I used this: 

xlimits = xlim;
xdiff = xlimits(2) - xlimits(1);
ylimits = ylim;
ydiff = ylimits(2) - ylimits(1);

dx = .0001;
dy = dx*ydiff/xdiff;

Comment: add "axis square" thsi will make sure the physical distance of each axis is the same.

Comment: I want to add an addendum since I found an even better solution. I found out these things are called wind barbs and someone else has made a matlab function for them: https://code.google.com/p/windbarb/ seems to work very well.